# Program run under x64dbg goes immediately to completion

Tags: windows, masm64

I'm using the x64dbg debugger from SourceForge under Windows 10, and I've been having a problem with it that I think is probably due to my own stupidity somehow, but so far I can't pin it down.

I'm using the MASM assembler, and when I'm working on a problem I will typically write a program consisting of only a few instructions, and then trace it with debugger to see exactly what's happening in a simple context.

I've been using a program called temp1 for a few weeks, and now suddenly when I run this program with the debugger, the debug data flashes for a fraction of a second on the x64dbg screen, and then the program runs to completion, as if I had clicked Debug → Run with no breakpoints.

I tried adding more instructions to the program, but the result was still the same. So then I renamed the program to bozo, and assembled and linked it under that name, with only two instructions in it. When I run `bozo.exe` under x64dbg, it stops on the first instruction with no problem.

What could be going on here? How can just using a different program name change the way the debugger behaves?

Comment: Evidently there are few if any x64dbg users out there. Is there a better debugger that I could be using instead under Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Options → Preferences* (Settings), and in the *Events* tab make sure to have `entry breakpoint` selected, so x64dbg breaks at the entry of your program, before it does anything.

Answer (score 0):

x64dbg saves settings, breakpoints, comments, etc. on the **debugee file name basis** - in the so-called "database".

For example, if your debugee was `bozo.exe` 64-bit executable, its database is saved in the `bozo.exe.dd64` file to keep your setting for future work with the same (`bozo.exe`) file.

The full path is something as

```
c:\Program Files\x64dbg\x64\db\bozo.exe.dd64
```

but it is not important as it is loaded automatically after opening / attaching the debugee `bozo.exe`.

**It explains why the simple *file-name change* (which creates a *new database with the default settings*) may change the behavior of the debugger.**

(The rest of the explanation is in the [Alicia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65768468/7023590).)